# Extract item id from url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to extract item ID from url of this structure:

```
http://site.com/items/123456/item_title_is_here.html
```

Item ID is 123456 in this case

Comment: what have you tried? There are a LOT of questions with answers that would be able to help you

Comment: I'm not so good in regex patterns so I didn't find any concrete answer, that's why I'm asking this simple question.

Comment: This off-topic? Maaaan....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$item = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$itemId = $item[4];
```

Comment: Great. It's just $item[4] but you gave me good idea.

Comment: Oh yes...I took only 'item'..Glad to help :)

Comment: I'm waiting these 5 mins here to be able to accept this answer ;)